# Matlab : replace each element with true/false value (logical array)

Tags: matlab, for-loop, conditional-statements

I've been wanting to loop through an array/matrix (instead of using a relational operator for the sake of practice/learning at this point), and if a simple condition is met, replace each element with either the true or false value, and ending up with a result array that is of the logical class.

```
vec = [5 9 3 4 6 11];

[r,c] = size(vec); 

vecempty = zeros(r,c);

for i = 1:r;
    for j = 1:c
        if vec(i,j) > 5;
            vecempty(i,j) = true;
        else
            vecempty(i,j) = false;
        end
    end
end

fprintf('Your truth matrix: \n\n\n') 

disp(vecempty) 

total = 0;

for i = 1:r;
    for j = 1:c;
        total = total + vecempty(i,j);
    end
end

fprintf('Total number of truth elements: %d \n\n\n', total)
```

For my "vec(i,j)" condition, I initially had them "= 1" or "=0", but I guessed this is just providing the numbers themselves, and not true or false. I thus went with the "=true" or "=false", but I'm wondering, why does the array I return (vecempty) not show up as a class of logical?

Following the same values:

```
Vectruth = vec > 5
```

The result "Vectruth" is returned as a logical class. I'm confused as to if I return "true" or "false" in my loop, why my resulting vector wouldn't be shown as a logical class, when with "vec > 5", it is shown as a logical class? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize a logical array by calling

```
vecempty = false(r,c);
```

instead of

```
vecempty = zeros(r,c);
```

Of course, `false` can be replaced by `true`, if appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, that does in indeed lead to my "vecempty" becoming a logical class. In what I did above however, is there a reason as to why my "vecempty" would not be recognized as a logical class?

Comment: When your array has been initialized as numerical and you try to assign a logical value to one of its elements, Matlab converts it to 0 or 1, leaving the array numerical. If you for some reason didn't know at start that you indeed wanted a logical array, you can convert it later by `logical(vecempty)`. But right now I don't see when such a situation might come up. Maybe you can clarify?

Comment: Generalizing what FliegenderZirkus said, when you index assign with parentheses into an initialized value, MATLAB coerces the value on the right-hand side of the assignment to the class of the left-hand side value. So the true and false are getting coerced to double, the type that vecempty was initialized to.